# not understanding AWS Amplify Authentication refresh token methods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am relatively new to app development and I don't understand something about aws amplify and cognito.  Let's say I use this method to sign in to an account:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

async function SignIn() {
    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn(username, password);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
}
```

Then you can make authenticated api calls using the credentials stored in user, correct?  But what if a user closes his browser and comes back later?  Wouldn't that data be erased and I would have to get new user values every time?  Do I do this programmatically?  Is there a way to store these credentials in the browser?

The article here:  http://medium.com/tensult/how-to-refresh-aws-cognito-user-pool-tokens-d0e025cedd52 says Amplify automatically refreshes tokens, but how does this work?  Can I assume the user value is always up to date?  I read that these tokens expire relatively quickly, how do I know when I need to refresh?

There's a layer here that I'm not understanding and the documentation isn't helping me (although it could very well be me).  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!